# why does sizes and srcset attributes of img tag not working?

Tags: html, image

I have an img tag with the attribute of "sizes".
but I don't know why it doesn't work

```
<img
  src="photo/gallery/tezos.jpg"
  alt=""
  srcset="photo/photo gallery/tezos@1x.jpg 1x,
  photo/photo gallery/tezos@2x.jpg 2x,
  photo/photo gallery/tezos@3x.jpg 3x"
  sizes="
  (max-width:600px) 100vw, (max-width:900px) 50vw, 33vw"
/>
```

also I think the "srcset" attribute doesn't work.
why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the source file by the attribute "srcset" not the "src". The srcset and sizes attributes work together to create responsive images.

Comment: i did above way but i have that problem

Comment: The `src` is optional and is used as a fallback for old browsers, so it's probably not the problem